# JavaFX external CSS through client-server mechanism

Tags: java, javafx-2, netty, fxml, javafx-css

I am using a client-server protocol using Netty. I am having a pre-loader and the main application in my Java program.

My question is, is it possible to fetch all needed CSS and FXML files from the server (using the pre-loader) and use them after the pre-loader is finished. If so, does anyone have an idea on how to do that?

Comment: Hm,why not using another with gui JavaFX program that downloads them  from the Server and when they are ready it calls the pre-loader of your main application.All that with notifications to the user,like a progress bar for example.

Comment: you load fxml files from directory right? everybody does, so why not direct your path to the path you downloaded the files to

Comment: Well, my goal is not to make any of my css or fxml files public. I don't want to store them locally on the client side.